# Get application directory from application name IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know a way to get the application's working directory from the application name? I have a list of all applications in IIS into a drop down list. When an application name is selected, i have an event fired. In that event, i need a way to get the selected application's working directory. I see a lot of examples of how to get the current working directory, but none for a referenced application.

Comment: The working directory should always be on the client.  User on the IIS have Guest privileges and have very little access to the IIS file system.  To get access you need to run an application as Admin which defeats the built-in security on the IIS.  If you need access then create a separate application on IIS with Admin privileges and set the access right so everybody can run the separate application so you limited capability of what the Guests can do.

Comment: I have a bunch of different applications on IIS, I am creating an admin application to manage the other sites. I am able to get all the application names, but how do i get their root directory? Some of the applications may be set up with a virtual path in IIS and not just sitting in the wwwroot folder. @jdweng

Comment: Get the  Environment Path and then search the path for the application name.           string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
            string[] paths = path.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();

Comment: That is what i was looking for. Thanks!